# I use Slim Framework. Why server response time is very big?

Tags: php, slim

I use this code, and server response in ~500-700ms. If write 'return;' after create Slim object as $app, response time is ~200-250ms. Why this framework work very slow? Can i do it fast?

```
    require 'Slim/Slim.php';
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();   
    $app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
        'debug' => true,
        'templates.path' => './templates'       
        ));    
    $headerType = $app->request->headers->get('Accept');
    switch($headerType){        
        case "text/html":
            $app->response->headers->set("Content-Type",'application/xml');
            echo  $headerType;
            break;
        case "application/xml":
            echo  $headerType;
            $app->response->headers->set("Content-Type",'application/xml');
            break;
          case 'application/json':
          default:
            $app->response->headers->set("Content-Type",'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    }

    $app->get('/modules/:id', function ($id) {  
        echo Modules::getJsonModule($id);       
    });

    $app->get('/countries/:id', function ($id) {    
        echo CountriesControls::getJsonCountry($id);        

    });

    $app->get('/modules/:id/childs', function ($id) {
        echo Modules::getJsonChilds($id);       
    });

    $app->get('/', function () {                    
    });

    $app->get('/modules/:id/summary', function ($id) {            
    });

    $app->run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you return immediately after you create the slim object, it does not get a chance to run which is why the response time is so fast.

If you want a faster responding website you need to look at how your application is constructed.

I run several different Slim websites and my response times are never above 250ms. My server is a cheap $5/mo from Digital Ocean.

A few things that help out,

**Caching:**

1) ETagging

2) Last Modified

**Fewer HTTP requests**

Minimize and concat all CSS and JS files

http://docs.slimframework.com/#HTTP-Caching-Overview

**Tools to help**

YSlow extension to Chrome, It represents a great first start to web application performance tuning.

Comment: Thanks! I found that worked slowly autoloading classes of my project. After optimization, the response time of less than 150-200 ms. I think it's normal rate.

Comment: I would still use YSlow to see your score. It does help out a lot. I also forgot to mention in your webserver config, you should have DEFLATE enabled